# Автоматический скроллинг страницы

Tags: jquery, html, прокрутка, блок, click

Добрый день! Есть скрипт вкладок. Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на вкладку страница автоматически скролилась вверх, где верх страницы будет верхняя точка самой вкладки блока .content Спасибо за помощь!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tab').on('click', function() {
        var $me = $(this);
        var id = $me.data("id");

        $('.content').hide();
        $('.content[data-id = ' + id + '-content]').show();

        $('.tab.tab-sel').removeClass('tab-sel');
        $('.tab[data-id=' + id + ']').addClass('tab-sel');
    });
});
```

Comment: Приложите HTML разметку к вопросу

Comment: Приветствую. Я понял, что вопрос вчерашний. Просто не очень понятно что у вас прыгает, ведь при переключении вкладки пользователь и так и так проскроллит до верха, чтоб ткнуть вкладку.

Comment: А так - могу подсказать, что в jQuery `var offset = $('<Элемент>').offset().top;` - узнать отступ от верха экрана. `$("body,html").animate({scrollTop: offset}, 500);` - плавно проскроллить к этому месту. 500 - это время в миллисекундах на анимацию

Comment: В таком случае ИМХО имеет смысл анимировать только клик по нижним вкладкам. Допустим нижним вкладкам дадим класс `.bottom`. Код изменится не сильно, сейчас напишу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tab').on('click', function() {
        var $me = $(this);
        var id = $me.data("id");
        var $tab = $('.tab[data-id=' + id + ']');
        var $tabBody = $('.content[data-id = ' + id + '-content]');

        $('.tab.tab-sel').removeClass('tab-sel');
        $tab.addClass('tab-sel');

        $('.content').fadeOut(500);
        $tabBody.fadeIn(500);

        //Если клик по нижней вкладке(Например класс .bottom)
        if($me.is('.bottom')) {
            var offset = $tabBody.offset().top;
            $("body,html").animate({scrollTop: offset}, 500);
        }
    });
});
```

Без анимации, если некрасиво получается

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tab').on('click', function() {
        var $me = $(this);
        var id = $me.data("id");
        var $tab = $('.tab[data-id=' + id + ']');
        var $tabBody = $('.content[data-id = ' + id + '-content]');

        $('.tab.tab-sel').removeClass('tab-sel');
        $tab.addClass('tab-sel');

        $('.content').hide();
        $tabBody.show();

        //Если клик по нижней вкладке(Например класс .bottom)
        if($me.is('.bottom')) {
            var offset = $tabBody.offset().top;
            $("body,html").scrollTop(offset);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @LADYX: Обращайтесь)

Comment: @LADYX: `var offset` это просто количество пикселей от верха страницы до элемента. Это число и с ним сделать можно любую математическую операцию. В вашем случае нужно скомпенсировать эти `60px`, подняв страницу выше. Тоесть отняв их от вычисленного отступа. `$("body,html").scrollTop(offset - 60);`

Comment: @LADYX: Само по себе число 60 прям в код лучше не вставлять, иначе получится так называемая "волшебная цифра". Я для наглядности вам так написал. Лучше вынести в отдельную переменную типа `var topMenuHeight = 60;` и подставлять уже ее, либо же вообще померить высоту этого фиксированного блока "налету".

Comment: @LADYX: Если вы оставите `offset - 60`, то через некоторое время можете забыть что такое 60 и почему это тут. Поздравляю, у вас получилась "магическая цифра" 60 в коде, которая является для вас загадкой. Запись `offset - topMenuHeight` однозначно говорит читающему, что из отступа вычли высоту верхнего меню. Обилие "магических цифр" в коде затруднит его восприятие, либо сделает попросту невозможным его чтение.

Comment: @LADYX: Спасибо вам, очень приятно слышать. Вам тоже удачи в постижении нашего нелегкого дела =)